# How check payment intent complete in flutter?

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I would greatly appreciate your help. In Flutter, when people press check out button, I call function "initPaymentSheet" like

```
await Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(
        paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
          customFlow: false,
          merchantDisplayName: 'Flutter Stripe Store Demo',
          paymentIntentClientSecret: data['client_secret'],
          customerEphemeralKeySecret: ephmeralKey,
          customerId: customerId,
          style: ThemeMode.dark,
        ),
      );
```

then I call `await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();` to present the payment sheet. After the customer completes the payment, the sheet is dismissed. Everything is normally, but I have one question: 'How do I check the payment status?' so that if the payment is successful, Flutter will call the API to remove all items from the shopping cart

I read docs of Stripe, they talk 'Use the Dashboard webhook tool or follow the webhook guide to receive these events and run actions' but I think in Flutter, the payment sheet automatically dismisses when the customer completes the payment, so it must have a payment event handler

Note that I am not a professional (I try to develop my own app) so I would really appreciate your help.

I thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe Docs is correct that, for business logic you should handle Payment status from webhook backend. Let's say your customer on a train with internet connectivity lost, or they went into a tunnel, or simply force closed your app, you would miss the business logic to handle successful Payment if you code it in Flutter.

[Flutter example app](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/example/lib/screens/payment_sheet/payment_sheet_screen.dart) only let the PaymentSheet disappearing. If there is no Exception caught, you can simply empty the cart here.